# Junit methods, annotated with @Before and @After, not working

Tags: java, junit

The @Before and @After method's print statementsa re not getting printed.
find the code below, what is the solution and possible reason for this

class MyMathTest {

```
MyMath myMath = new MyMath();

@Before
public  void before()
{
    System.out.println("runs before");
}




@Test
public void sum_with3numbers () {

    System.out.println("test 1");
    int result = myMath.sum(new int[] {1,2,3});

    assertEquals(6,result);
}

@Test
public void sum_with1numbers () {

    System.out.println("test 2");
    int result = myMath.sum(new int[] {1,2,3});

    assertEquals(6,result);
}


@After
public void after()
{
    System.out.println("runs after every test");
}
```

}

Output :
test1
test2

Comment: How are you executing your tests? Are you, by any chance, calling the test methods manually instead of running the junit test suite?

Comment: Are you running it as a main class or in a test runner? JUnit has its own classes that must be run in order to run a test.

Comment: i am running it as Junit class only.. what i could find is BeforeEach & AfterEach ran successfully, as JUnit5 minght not support  Before & After , may be not sure but it didnt work out. but still  BeforeClass is not working @Yserbius

Comment: JUnit 5 has BeforeAll methinks?